# Is it possible to let people add cards in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I have created a public board for one of my products.

I want to give permission to everyone to add a card (a new idea). They are not necessarily team members. They could be anonyme, but ideally, they need to log in to add cards.

Does anyone know if it is possible in Trello?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with Trello's invite collaborators by URL feature (currently in beta).

**Steps**

1. Show Menu
2. Add Members > `Invite people by giving them a special link…`
3. Place the URL in a conspicuous place like your website or a Readme card of some sort along with some instructions for your collaborators.

**Demo**

[image: Demo of Trello's Invite by URL]

Comment: Will this give them permission to modify/delete other cards too?